Given a discrete probability distribution on [m], what is the largest set of sequences of length $n$ where each $i$ occurs with probability $p_i$?
Suppose I have a probability distribution $p_{i}$ on the set $[m]$ of integers from $1$ up to $m$ inclusive and some integer $n$. How can I find the biggest subset of sequences of length $n$ such that if I sample an integer from the subset, in the sense of picking a random sequence, and then picking a random integer $i$ in that sequence, I pick $i$ with probability $p_i$. Of course I am only interested in the case where there actually exists such a subset at all, which doesn't happen for most $p_i$.
The relevance of this is that I am trying to bound how badly particular sequences can go wrong. And so I have a set of 'bad' sequences. I somehow want to say that no particular $i$ can happen too often, as long as I know I have sufficiently many distinct sequences.
